# RShiny Code executes multiple times when it runs

Tags: r, shiny

I have the code below and it allows a user to upload an excel, rename the columns, and then do some quick analysis around top terms, etc (the first column MUST be named 'Comments').

What is happening is that when I upload my file > rename my first column > then click on the quick analysis, it runs the code 4 times so it's constantly refreshing. I removed the other 3 tables I have in there to make it easier. I'm thinking I need to `isolate()` function somewhere, but I'm not sure.

```
   # Toy Example.

library(needs)
needs(
  shiny,
  ggplot2,
  tidyverse,
  shinydashboard,
  DT,
  shinycssloaders,
  plotly,
  shinyjs,
  dashboardthemes,
  reactable,
  quanteda
)



## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

convertMenuItem <- function(mi, tabName) {
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-toggle'] = "tab"
  mi$children[[1]]$attribs['data-value'] = tabName
  mi
}

header = dashboardHeader()

sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
  width = 300,

  sidebarMenu(
    id = 'panelsbar',
    convertMenuItem(tabName = 'home', menuItem(
      'Home', tabName = 'home', icon = icon('home')
    )),
    convertMenuItem(
      tabName = 'data',
      menuItem(
        'Data Input',
        tabName = 'data',
        fileInput(
          "file",
          "Upload CSV files",
          multiple = TRUE,
          accept = ("text/comma")
        ),
        uiOutput('textColumn'),
        actionButton('go', 'Run')
      )
    ),
    convertMenuItem(
      tabName = 'variables',
      menuItem('Variable Renaming', tabName = 'variable',
               uiOutput("renamer"))
    ),
    convertMenuItem(tabName = 'quickAnalysis',
                    menuItem('Quick Analysis',
                             tabName = 'quickAnalysis'))
    
    
  )
)


body <- dashboardBody(
  shinyDashboardThemes('grey_light'),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = 'home'),
    tabItem(tabName = 'data',
            fluidRow(
              box(
                width = 12,
                title = 'Data Input',
                solidHeader = T,
                status = 'primary',
                collapsible = T,
                reactableOutput('rawData')
              )
            )),
    tabItem(tabName = 'variable',
            dataTableOutput("rename")),
    tabItem(tabName = 'quickAnalysis',
            fluidRow(
              box(
                width = 6,
                title = 'Top Terms',
                solidHeader = T,
                plotlyOutput('topTerms')
              ),
              box(
                width = 6,
                title = 'Top bigrams',
                solidHeader = T,
                dataTableOutput('topBis')
              )
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(
                width = 6,
                title = 'Top 75 Terms',
                solidHeader = T,
                plotOutput('wordcloudTopTerms') %>%
                  withSpinner()
              ),
              box(width = 6, dataTableOutput('x1'))
            ))
    
    
  )
)



ui = shinydashboard::dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body,
                                   tags$head(tags$style(
                                     HTML(".sidebar {
                      height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;
                    }")
                                   )))


server = server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30 * 1024 ^ 2)
  
  
  dataa <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    read.csv(input$file$datapath)
  })
  
  
  output$contents <- renderDataTable({
    dataa()
  })
  
  
  output$rawData = renderReactable({
    reactable(
      dataa(),
      filterable = T,
      resizable = T,
      showPagination = T,
      showSortIcon = T,
      defaultPageSize = 10
    )
  })
  
  
  
  # rename variables --------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  
  output$renamer <- renderUI({
    lapply(colnames(dataa()), function(i) {
      textInput(paste0("col_", i), i, i)
    })
  })
  
  
  DataRename <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    Data <- dataa()
    DataNew1 <- Data
    
    for (i in names(input)) {
      if (grepl(pattern = "col_", i)) {
        colnames(DataNew1)[which(colnames(DataNew1) == substr(i, 5, nchar(i)))] =
          input[[i]]
      }
      
    }
    
    return(DataNew1)
  })
  
  output$rename <- renderDataTable({
    DataRename()
  })
  
  
  
  numComments = reactive({
    sum(!is.na(df$Comments))
  })
  
  
  
  # Text analysis -----------------------------------------------------------
  x = do.call(c,
              unlist(stopwords::data_stopwords_marimo$en, recursive = F))
  x = c(stopwords(), x, 'takeda')
  x = c(x, stopwords::data_stopwords_stopwordsiso$en)
  stop_words = unique(x)
  
  corp =  reactive({
    req(DataRename())
    x = corpus(DataRename(), text_field = 'Comments')
  })
  
  
  dm = reactive({
    df = DataRename()
    corp = corp()
    
    x = corp %>%
      dfm(
        tolower = T,
        remove = stop_words,
        remove_punct = T,
        remove_symbols = T,
        remove_numbers = T
      )
  })
  
  topTerms = reactive({
    dm = dm()
    x = dm() %>%
      textstat_frequency()
  })
  getTopTerms = reactive({
    x = topTerms()
    x %>% as.data.frame() %>%
      mutate(Frequency = round((docfreq / numComments()) * 100, 1)) %>%
      select(-c(group, frequency, rank)) %>%
      rename(Count = docfreq,
             Terms = feature)
    
  })
  
  plotTerms = reactive({
    top = getTopTerms()
    top = top %>% arrange(desc(Frequency)) %>% top_n(15)
    p = plot_ly(
      data = top,
      type = 'bar',
      y = ~ Terms,
      x =  ~ Frequency,
      source = 'topterms'
    )
    p
  })
  
  output$topTerms = renderPlotly({
    plotTerms()
  })
  
  
  
  
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: DataRename has a reactive dependency on `input` (through the line `for (i in names(input)) {`, did you try isolating that? A reactive that is dependent on `input` refreshes when *any* input changes.

Comment: ahhh  okay so it would be something like `isolate( for (i in names(input)) {
      if (grepl(pattern = "col_", i)) {
        colnames(DataNew1)[which(colnames(DataNew1) == substr(i, 5, nchar(i)))] =
          input[[i]]
      )`

Comment: Ted, I don't think so, since technically you do want to react to text fields, don't you? If you only want to react when the "go" button is pressed, then yes, you can isolate the `input[[i]]` as well. I don't think it's a good idea in general to `isolate` a large expression like that, though I don't know of any technical hurdles or limitations other than chainsaw-fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reactivity graph has too many edges, among other things.

[image: shiny dependency graph]

(Symbols borrowed from https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html)

For starters, `DataRename` depends on `dataa()` and `input$file`, but `dataa` already depends on `input$file`. So whenever `input$file` changes, both `dataa` and `DataRename` fire. Once `dataa` fires, then it triggers `DataRename` *again*. If you must have `input$file` in `DataRename`, then use `isolate(input$file)` there.

Further, `DataRename` looks at everything within `input$`, so ... whenever anything is updated in any input anywhere, `DataRename` is triggered. Therefore, everything downstream of `DataRename` is also triggered, even if unnecessarily.

`dm` also has a redundant dependency with `corp` and `DataRename`, where `corp` already depends on `DataRename`.

Another minor concern is that `numComments` references `df`, but I cannot find where it is defined in its view. Check to make sure you are not reaching out to the calling environment and finding a `df` hanging around. (If so, then this app may work locally but will fail when deployed.)

Possible fixes, untested:

```r
  DataRename <- reactive({
    req(isolate(input$file))
    Data <- dataa()         # okay, ...
    DataNew1 <- Data        # this is an unnecessary indirection, no gains
    inpnames <- names(isolate(input))
    for (i in inpnames) {
      if (grepl(pattern = "col_", i)) {
        colnames(DataNew1)[which(colnames(DataNew1) == substr(i, 5, nchar(i)))] =
          input[[i]]
      }
      
    }
    
    return(DataNew1)
  })

  dm = reactive({
    # df = isolate(DataRename()) # not used, can remove entirely?
    corp = corp()
    
    x = corp %>%
      dfm(
        tolower = T,
        remove = stop_words,
        remove_punct = T,
        remove_symbols = T,
        remove_numbers = T
      )
  })
```

Comment: wow this is insanely helpful!!! the chart is really great to understand everything. so pretty much every red line is a redundant or a problem and I should fix? For now, I've removed the whole variable renaming tab and it works as expected but i'm planning on adding it back in.

Comment: The red lines are those that I thought were problematic. I made this manually, mostly because I don't have enough of the dependencies to be able to use shiny reactlog; you can generate something like it yourself using https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/articles/reactlog.html.

Comment: I'll often use the reactlog to prove to myself that what I think is happening is really happening ... and then see that I did it to myself, as the dependency-connectors do not lie.